# Upgrading from IIS 7.0 to IIS 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Is there any mandatory to add asp.net website folder application into local IIS server to check web application in the localhost. As of now When I press debug from visual studio 2015, my application is running successfully in localhost. So could you please let me know shall I need to add or not in local IIS.

My current asp.net web application is in IIS 7.0 and now I am planning to upgrade it to IIS 10 for TLS 1.2 version of security in paypal so in these process shall I need to check or not in local system which had IIS 10. If yes could you please let me know how integrate web application in local IIS 10 with step by step.

Comment: I whish you would formulate a paragraph that makes sense. As it is, it is unclear what you are asking. Particularly because you do not upgrade IIS - you upgrade windows, IIS versions are tied to windows versions.

Comment: Why don't you just follow the same steps you used for IIS 7, and if something doesn't just work edit that into your question and we can help you solve that issue. I'd expect Visual Studio integration will just work as before - I can't imagine the admin interfaces it uses will have changed - but if not then upgrading to Visual Studio 2017 ought to fix that.

Comment: @TomTom Thank you for feedback. As of now I made my concern clear.